# rails, 2 iterations of acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, voting

I have an acts_as_votable voting system working right now.

But, I want to add a second vote link/button system to the same model/user group to track another type of vote. How would I go about doing this? I was thinking to create a whole new table/etc. but thinking if there is an easier solution to track another vote within the same tables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

#### Votable model can be voted under different scopes by the same user:

```
@post.vote_by :voter => @user1, :vote_scope => 'week'
@post.vote_by :voter => @user1, :vote_scope => 'month'
```

You can get the votes by scope:

```
@post.find_votes_for(:vote_scope => 'rank')
```

---

There is alot you can do with [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem, you don't need to create new table.